# Get random multiple database records and save them in a single string column in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database table which contains more than 100 questions. And I have another table for the exams. I have only a single column for the questions.

What I need to do is getting a random 20 questions ID's from the first table and insert them in the single string column by splitting the ID's inside the column like (8,20,60,75)

What is the best way to do that with EF code first?

Comment: As an aside, storing multiple ids as a string like you are suggesting is very very bad! Multiple questions **per day** are asked on StackOverflow on issues arising from storing a concatenated string of IDs, and the first advice given is always "DON"T DO IT" :) you will be causing yourself a headache for years to come. You should be using a linking table... not a single column - and EF handles that propertly.

Comment: Getting random records is as simple as `select top 5 from Table order by newid()`

Comment: @DaleK I'd love to use a linking table but the questions number is not fixed, and to have a table column for each question would be harder because i can't create an unlimited columns

Comment: A linking table is precisely for when the question number is not fixed... you add a record for each question which should be linked to the exam. It only needs 3 columns, ExamID, QuestionID, & Position. Where Position is an int used to order the questions.

Comment: @DaleK My exam system here is quit different from what you suggest, I have a section table linked to the questions. it's like  a math section that contains a math-related questions... so when i create an exam i only mention the section and the questions number, so it should get (x) questions from the section into the exam, and it should be random questions each time so i can't just link the questions and save it.. i hope you know what's in my mind now

Comment: Nothing you have said changes the situation, if you are going to store 5 random questions in a single column, you can just as easily store those 5 random questions in a linking table. And in fact you should!

Comment: @DaleK So i think i shall try what you said, thank you for your patience.